# Can't disable number grouping with primefaces inputText

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to remove the number grouping in a primefaces inputText but it still does it no matter what.

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.ammount}"
                     onfocus="selectOnFocus(this)" onkeyup="applyLocaleToCurrency(this)">
                    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this"/>
                    <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2">
</p:inputText>
```

I tried with the above code as wellbut still nothing.

Any help?

Comment: So it works if you use an `h:inputText`? or don't use ajax? Or don't use the `onfocus` or `onkeyup`?

Comment: Yea actually in the applyLocaleToCurrency(...) method, javascript is setting the value to a number with grouping.

This is what my javascriptMethod does: `$(e).val(Number($(e).val()).toLocaleString())`

Comment: See, therefore ALWAYS start creating an [mcve]. Remove more and more until it either suddenly works or you find something that causes the problem... please keep this in mind for next questions!!! And in this case the functionname should have been an alarm bell

Answer (score 0):

onkeyup="applyLocaleToCurrency(this)" the javascript method is setting a value to the field which has number grouping.